# jquery plugin can't use in angular

Tags: jquery, angular, jquery-ui, rateyo

Is this possible to use `jQuery plugin` in `Angular 5`, for example `jQuery UI` and `jQuery RateYo!`? I can't implement in my project. If it is possible give ideas or example codes, please help to solve this issue. I am using **npm install rateyo**

example code given below:

**html**

```
<div id="rateYo"></div>
```

**ts**

```
$("#rateYo").rateYo({
    rating: 3.6
});
```

Comment: Kinda hard to tell you what the problem is with it, without any information. Check your console and see if you get any errors, check if you have included jQuery correct.

Comment: You need to show us how you import the plugin's files

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for jQuery at all if you are using Angular. I would not mix them together, because they are very different. Loading jQuery will only make your code base bigger without any obvious benefit.

Plus there is already several angular directives with the exact functionality, why don't you use some of them?

Try this directive. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-jk-rating-stars